# Play Framework - passing parameter to an action from another action in controller using Cache

Tags: scala, caching, controller, playframework-2.2

I have a form that is submitted from `view`, before processing the form I checked the role, if everything is alright then I will `insert/edit/delete/approve` the data depends on which submit button is pressed, like below:

```
def input_form = withAccess { username => implicit request =>
        submitSOForm.bindFromRequest.fold (
           hasErrors = { form =>
                ....
            )},
            success = { userData =>
                if (Sales_Order.check(userData,"insert")) {
                    //using cache to pass the userData
                    Cache.set("userData", userData, 60)
                    if(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("action")(0) == "Save" || request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("action")(0) == "Ask for Approval")
                        Redirect(routes.SalesOrders.insert(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("action")(0)))
                    else
                        Redirect(routes.SalesOrders.approval("insert", request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("action")(0)))
                }
                else
                    Redirect(routes.SalesOrders.index).withSession(Security.username -> username, "timestamp" -> System.currentTimeMillis.toString).flashing(Flash() + ("invalid" -> "Inconsistent Input Data.") + ("insert" -> "block"))
            }
        )
    }
```

Everything works fine, I can get the `userData` either in insert or approval action method. However, I'm not sure using cache is the right choice. I imagine if there is a lot of request to `input_form`, then it will remove arbitrary data from the cache which is explained in the [documentary](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaCache).

```
An important point about the cache is that it behaves just like a cache should: 
the data you just stored may just go missing.
```

So, what I'm asking here is there any better way to passing that `userData` without using `Cache` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is: you don't need to afraid cache's loose between requests - it's rather information that you shouldn't use it as a *regular* persistence layer.

For main question: most probably [**Flash** scope](http://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaSessionFlash) will be more suitable solution for this task.

Remember that cache values will be available for other users, so if some user will perform similar action in the almost the same time (60 seconds) it will get value from others action - Flash as it's stored in the cookie will be individual.

If you want to stay with cache - (i.e. in case that you want to store objects much bigger than 4kb) at least make sure that the cache **keys** contains some user specific, unique elements, like:

```
Cache.set("userData"+currentUser.id, userData, 60)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Flash and Cache availability. However, my userData type is `case class Sales_Order(...)`, so when I do flashing like `.flashing(Flash() + ("userData" -> userData))`, it shows compilation error because `String` expected. How to overcome that issue ?

Comment: So as I pointed in last paragraph make sure that cache key is UNIQUE per user... you can also mix both approaches = store object in the cache with some very random, unique key and then pass the key (as a string) to next action with flash scope

Comment: I know what you meant, however after reading your explanation I prefer using only Flash rather than Cache if possible. So my question now, is Flash can only pass a String ? or Is there a way to pass `userData` without the use of Cache ?

Comment: Don't waste your time! just use Cache+Flash approach, reason is simple: Flash allows only strings AND flash is size limited (as it's cookie it can be max 4kb size max), maybe you won't believe but I have some... experience ;)